# How to generate more than 5 random prime number

Tags: c

Apparently I am able to generate prime numbers from a given range and display them,today I was trying to add,multiply and subtract prime numbers without displaying all of them but rather by using a random generator to pick more than 5 random prime numbers and add them or subtract or multiply from a given range of 2-500. I have searched and i found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769680/random-prime-number) but it doesn't answer my question. The rest I found are done in other languages. I don't want to have an array of the primes done manually.

Code;

```
for ( count = 2 ; count <= n ;  )
   {
      for ( c = 2 ; c <= i - 1 ; c++ )
      {
         if ( i%c == 0 )
            break;
      }
      if ( c == i )
      {
         printf("%d\n",i);
         count++;
      }
      i++;
```

I really need help on how i can generate more than 5 random prime numbers and `+,-,*` to get an answer..

Comment: Generate 5 random indices, and then use them to index into the sequence of prime numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most elegant way to generate prime numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042902/most-elegant-way-to-generate-prime-numbers)

Comment: That's in C#? I wanted it In c.